# Using SNMP4J with logback

Tags: java, java-8, logback, slf4j, snmp4j

We are using SLF4J and logback in our application code and SNMP4J has log4j as dependency.

Can someone let me know how can I make SNMP4J work with logback?

Version

- SNMP4J - 2.4.3
- Logback - 1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own LogAdapter and LogFactory implementation for logback.
That should be quite simple. You can start with the Log4JLogAdatper and Log4JLogFactory as example.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want all logging, be it JUL, Log4J, SLF4J, JCL or logback, logged by slf4j/logback. You can get that by adding these packages to classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</dependency>
```

For JUL (java.util.logging) you need to call two extra methods:

```
org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
```

With this configuration, you are free to use any logging framework in SNMP4J. Example for Log4J:

```
LogFactory.setLogFactory(new Log4jLogFactory());
```

You might have to exclude Log4J from the transitive SNMP4J dependencies (I'll remove this part if it's obsolete now):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.snmp4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>snmp4j</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

And for the records, the slf4j/logback dependencies do look like this (example):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</dependency>
```